# Where to ask "Why the radio cuts out in a specific tunnel"?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about a phenomenon that occurs while driving through the George Massey Tunnel. Where can I post that question?

The question is:
Why does the radio cut out while in the George Massey Tunnel?
Is it the river? Is it the concrete that lines said tunnel?

On which Stack Exchange site can I ask this question?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question. Asking why the radio cuts out is off-topic on MSE. But asking _where_ on SE you can ask this, is on-topic.

Comment: Though my account has been here on SE for a year or so, I haven't really used it at all.  I'd like to know where to ask this on SE because I've always been curious about this.

Comment: It _might_ be on-topic on Physics Stack Exchange. But, I'd wait a bit before posting there. Maybe somebody here has a better suggestion.

Comment: point taken, I'll give it a week or so i guess.

Comment: Question edited to better reflect what I was going for - the questino isn't abuot the video, rather the phenomenon that occurs when you drive thruogh the Georbe Massey Tunnel in BC.

Comment: No idea who Andrew is, but voted to reopen as site recommendation questions are on topic here.

Comment: Cheers, one more vote is needed.

Comment: I will link the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOXr-FYSGgg it shows the phenomenon happening and may help you guys figure out where best to askthis question.

Comment: If the radio isn't connected to the radio station by wire, that means it's using radio waves to reach your car.  Radio waves can be interfered with, if you didn't know.  Stuff like metal and dense structures.  And dense structures full of metal.  Also, radios and their antenna vary in quality, and so are affected differently by such interference.  There.  Now you don't have to ask.

Comment: I ask the question because it is the only tunnel in which this has happened in my experience.  I was in one in Europe and the radio was really clear, and that tunnel was longer and further down than the Massey Tunnel.  unless the river above was causing interference.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean the question is about the video itself, I'm afraid there is no such site in Stack Exchange.

There is [Movies & TV](//movies.stackexchange.com/), but it's only for cinema/TV movies/shows, not YouTube videos. There is also [Web Applications](//webapps.stackexchange.com) site, with [youtube tag](//webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube), but it clearly says:

> For questions about the web interface of YouTube

So questions about video contents will be off topic there as well.

You can [propose a new site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), otherwise I'm afraid you'll just have to look elsewhere.

Comment: I've been thinking Physics, Electronics or Amateur Radio. None of them _quite_ fit, but they are the ones who might know the answer.

Comment: @S.L.Barth well, in such case mentioning the video was irrelevant. (OP's fault of course, not yours)

Comment: The video is meant to show an example of what happens when you enter the George Massey tunnel with the radio going.